# Merging two array together

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok, I have 2 array from json.
getBalances returns

```
 [{Currency=USD, Balance=3.25},
  {Currency=CNY, Balance=4.56},
  {Currency=CAD, Balance=4.56},
  {etc},
  {etc}]
```

and getValues returns

```
 [{Currency=USDJPY, Equivilent=0.12},
  {Currency=USDCNT, Equivilent=0.75},
  {Currency=USDJPN, Equivilent=0.75},
  {etc},
  {etc}]
```

There are over 100 Currencies and 3 responding pairs max, with a minimum of 1 for each.

I'm looking for an example of how to take these arrays, and combine them to be.

```
{Currency=USD, Balance=3, USDCNY=0.12, USDJPN=0.75, USDCAD=0.75},
```

If anyone can give me a starting point to look at or a sample code with an explain and reference that would be cool. I'm at a loss on how I would do this and my google fu is letting me down.

---

```
function getValues(){
  //var balancesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Balances");
  //var exchange = balancesSheet.getRange(1,1,150,1);
  var finals = [];
  var endpoint = "someapiendpoint"
  var results = publicRequest(endpoint); // calls function to create url and returns json
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(results.getContentText());
  var dataSet = dataAll;
   dataSet.forEach(function(result,index) {
    finals.push({'Currency': result.symbol, 'Equivilent': result.price})
  });
  finals.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.Currency < b.Currency) return -1;
    if(a.Currency > b.Currency) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
 // Logger.log(finals);    
  return json2array_(finals);

};

function loadBalances(){
  var balancesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Balances");
  balancesSheet.getRange(1,1,150,2).clearContent();
  var balances = getbalances();
  var arr = json2array_(balances);
  var removeZerobalances = arr.filter(function(item){ return item[1] != 0 });  
  var destinationRange = balancesSheet.getRange(1,1,removeZerobalances.length,removeZerobalances[0].length);
  destinationRange.setValues(removeZerobalances);
};

function getbalances() {
  var finals = [];
  var endpoint = "someapiendpoint"
  var results = privateRequest(endpoint,"timestamp="+nonce); // calls function to create url and json
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(results.getContentText());
  var dataSet = dataAll;

  dataSet.balances.forEach(function(result,index) {
    finals.push({'Currency': result.asset, 'Balance': result.free})
  });
  //Logger.log(finals);
  return finals;
};

function json2array_(data){
  var results = [];
  var keys = [];
  var values = [];
  for (var i in data){
    for (var Key in data[i]){
      if (i == 0) keys.push(Key);
      values.push(data[i][Key]);
    }
    if (i == 0){
      results.push(keys);
      keys = [];
    }
    results.push(values);
    values = [];
  }
  return results;
};
```

Comment: This doesn't look like JSON. Where are you getting `{Dad=Joe, Kids=3}` from?

Comment: Try breaking your main goal (merging arrays by rules) into smaller, more manageable, goals (check if a string variable contains a substring `x`, create a variable that's named after a value, etc.)

Comment: Cody, they are example of arrays created from json exracted from a private api. Thanks GalAbra, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Do you get such data using Google Apps Script? If you use it, such data can be used as an object.

Comment: I am using google apps script.

Comment: I have though of using multiple spreadsheets and Filling the array in to one spread sheet and then grabbing it and just adding to the other, but the issue I forsee there is when certain values of the array are 0 i have the row removed. things won't line up after doing it hat way.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can we see your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike, added my code and made the examples more along the lines of what the code does.

Comment: Load balnces will need to be changed when the currency pair prices are added to the balances.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you show us where are 2 arrays of your initial question in your additional script? Because there are no ``{'Currency': result.symbol, 'Equivilent': result.price}`` and ``{'Currency': result.asset, 'Balance': result.free}`` in the 2 arrays.

Comment: @Tanaike arrays added to match functions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you want to marge each object which were returned at function ``getbalances()`` and ``getValues()``? If it's so, can you explain us the reason that ``{Currency=USD, Balance=3, USDCNY=0.12, USDJPN=0.75, USDCAD=0.75},`` in your question can be obtained from them?

Comment: I want to merge each base currency from getBalances(), with its pairs from the getValues(). I feel it would be possible to push a new column for each pair, then fill it with the corresponding values. That got me thinking of a partial solution.

Comment: I posted an answer from your additional information. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Apps Script, when an object is seen using `Logger.log()`, `key` and `value` are seen as `key=value`. This can be used as an object. So how about this sample script? By comparing `Currency` of data from `getBalances()` with the top characters of data from `getValues()`, `Currency` and `Equivilent` of `getValues()` are retrieved.

#### Sample script :

```
var obj1 = getBalances();
var obj2 = getValues();
var res = [];
obj1.forEach(function(e1){
  var temp = {
    Currency: e1.Currency,
    Balance: e1.Balance
  };  
  obj2.forEach(function(e2){
    if (e2.Currency.slice(0, e1.Currency.length) == e1.Currency) {
      temp[e2.Currency] = e2.Equivilent;
    }
  });
  res.push(temp);
});
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Sample result :

Input :

```
var obj1 = [{Currency: "USD", Balance: 3.25},{Currency: "CNY", Balance: 4.56},{Currency: "CAD", Balance: 4.56}];
var obj2 = [{Currency: "USDJPY", Equivilent: 0.12},{Currency: "USDCNT", Equivilent: 0.75},{Currency: "USDJPN", Equivilent: 0.75}];
```

Output :

```
[
    {
        "Currency": "USD",
        "Balance": 3.25,
        "USDJPY": 0.12,
        "USDCNT": 0.75,
        "USDJPN": 0.75
    },
    {
        "Currency": "CNY",
        "Balance": 4.56
    },
    {
        "Currency": "CAD",
        "Balance": 4.56
    }
]
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: Thank you. That's pretty much what I am looking to do. But I'm getting TypeError: Cannot call method "slice" of undefined.

Comment: I removed using json2array_() from the getValues() and only returned the var finals and it removed the TypeError.